# JavaScript: How to get an alert after two buttons have been pressed

Tags: javascript, function, onkeydown

I need to make a function that detects `onkeydown` events that are specified in the first argument (`keyset`) of a function (`reqKeysToFunc`). Once detected this will call a function that is specified in the second argument of the function (`myFunc`).

My current code below displays an alert when either <kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>M</kbd> is pressed, but I want the alert to show after *both* of them have been pressed, instead of just one. Also, I want to be able to put in different letters for the `keyset` argument, but I don't know how to define this within the function.

```
function reqKeysToFunc( keySet, myFunc) {
    document.onkeydown = function(event) {
        "use strict";
        var myKey = event.key.toUpperCase();
        var keySet = 'ZM';
        if (keySet.search(myKey) > -1 ) {
            document.onkeydown = null;
            myFunc();
        }
    }
}

function tmp() {
    alert('hello');
}

reqKeysToFunc('ZM', tmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

This example lets you define an array of sequences to look for.  It stores the partial sequence a user is typing in a global called currentSequence.  If an entire sequence is typed successfully myFunc is called with the sequence that was typed.

```js
var sequences = ['ZM', 'AB'];
var currentSequence = "";

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  "use strict";
  var myKey = event.key.toUpperCase();
  // see if the current sequence is valid
  var valid = sequences.filter(function (el) {
    return el.indexOf(currentSequence + myKey) === 0;
  });
  if (!valid.length) {
    // current sequence is not valid, start over
    currentSequence = "";
  } else {
    currentSequence += myKey;
    // see if the current sequence is complete
    var found = valid.indexOf(currentSequence);
    if (found > -1) {
      // user typed a complete sequence
      myFunc(currentSequence);
      currentSequence = "";
    }
  }
}

function myFunc(sequence) {
  alert("You typed " + sequence);
}
```

```html
Type stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job.
You store pressed key in the object. And check if number of different pressed keys from set equals number of letters in set.

```
function reqKeysToFunc( keySet, myFunc) {
    var pressedKeys = {};

    document.onkeydown = function(event) {
        "use strict";
        var myKey = event.key.toUpperCase();
        //var keySet = 'ZM';  //remove this line - keySet is defined as an argument
        if (keySet.search(myKey) > -1 ) {
            pressedKeys[myKey] = true;
            document.onkeydown = null;

            if(pressedKeys.entries().filter((key, val) => val).length === keySet.length) {
                myFunc();
            }
        }
    }
}

function tmp() {
    alert('hello');
}

reqKeysToFunc('ZM', tmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want the alert to show after both of them have been pressed, instead of just one.

You could do that with the use of flags for each key that you want to detect.  When <kbd>Z</kbd> has been pressed, the `zFlag` variable is set to `true`. When <kbd>M</kbd> has been pressed, the `mFlag` variable is set to `true`.  Only once both flags have been set will the `alert` function be called.

See this example:

```js
var zFlag = false,
  mFlag = false;

function reqKeysToFunc(keySet, myFunc) {
  document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    "use strict";
    var myKey = event.key.toUpperCase();
    var keySet = 'ZM';
    if (keySet.search(myKey) > -1) {
      if (myKey == 'Z') { // if Z was pressed
        zFlag = true;
      } else { // if M was pressed
        mFlag = true;
      }
      if (zFlag && mFlag) { // if both keys have been pressed
        document.onkeydown = null;
        myFunc();
      }
    }
  }
}

function tmp() {
  alert('hello');
}

reqKeysToFunc('ZM', tmp);
document.body.focus(); // so you don't have to click before typing
```

> Also, I want to be able to put in different letters for the keyset argument, but I don't know how to define this within the function.

You have the basis for dynamically defining the keyset: passing it in as an argument to `reqKeysToFunc()`.  You just need to remove the static `var keyset` declaration inside the function, create an array to store which keys have been pressed and which ones haven't, and then check each key pressed.

See this solution (with `ZMD` passed in as the keyset):

```js
var zFlag = false,
  mFlag = false;

function reqKeysToFunc(keySet, myFunc) {
  var keySetArray = keySet.split(''); // get an array of keys
  document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    "use strict";
    var myKey = event.key.toUpperCase();
    if (keySetArray.indexOf(myKey) > -1) {
      keySetArray.splice(keySetArray.indexOf(myKey), 1); // remove the pressed key from the array
      if (!keySetArray.length) { // if all keys have been pressed
        document.onkeydown = null;
        myFunc();
      }
    }
  }
}

function tmp() {
  alert('hello');
}

reqKeysToFunc('ZMD', tmp);
document.body.focus(); // so you don't have to click before typing
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this which seems to have worked:

```
function reqKeysToFunc( keySet, myFunc) {
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    "use strict";
    var myKey = event.key.toUpperCase();

    if (keySet.search(myKey) > -1 ) {
        keySet = keySet.replace(myKey, '');
        if(keySet === '') {
            document.onkeydown = null;
            myFunc();
            }
        }
    }
}

function tmp() {
    alert('hello');
}

reqKeysToFunc('ZM', tmp);
```

Answer (score -3):

Declare a variable and save count on that on button click , then check if button get click and variable has value 1 then show alert

Comment: That would show the alert if either Z or M is pressed twice, rather than only if both keys have been pressed.